# Understanding the Lorentz Equations

Tags: special-relativity

We know that if there are two observers S and S', they will observe some events on the space-time and their relation is given as

$$\Delta x = \gamma(\Delta x' + \beta \Delta c t')$$
$$\Delta ct = \gamma(\Delta ct' + \beta \Delta x')$$

Now my problems is about the meanings of the $\Delta x$ and $\Delta x'$. If we have a one meter stick. And if this stick is at rest w.r.t S, then we will say that $\Delta x = 1$, however if we have a stick and if its at rest with respect to S', then we are still using $\Delta x = 1$.

So $\Delta x$ or $\Delta ct$ is the quantities that is always measured in the rest frame and it does not matter either it is S or S' ?

In other words $\Delta x$ and $\Delta ct$ are measured w.r.t a rest frame ?

In general how can one define what is $\Delta x$ and $\Delta x'$ ? Since it seems they are not just defined under who is moving and who is at rest but who is measuring the quantity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are measuring the length of an object in $S$ or in $S'$:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\Delta x$ is the distance between two events at the same time in frame $S$.

\item $\Delta x'$ is the distance between two events at the same time in frame $S'$.
\end{itemize}
In general, $\Delta x$ and $\Delta x'$ are the differences in $x$ coordinates between events in either frame (which can also involve a non-zero change in time).

If you have a meter stick in frame $S$ (ie, the meter stick is at rest in $S$), then you can call the distance between the ends of the meter stick at some time $\Delta x=1{\rm m}$ (note that since we are measuring the ends of the meter stick at the same time, $\Delta t=0)$. Then, you can use the Lorentz transformations to infer the distance $\Delta x'$ and time interval $\Delta t'$ that the observer $S'$ will measure between these two events.

This also works the other way. If you have a meter stick in $S'$, you can measure the distance between the two ends of the meter stick. We can call this $\Delta x_2'$. Note that $\Delta t_2'=0$. (I've put a 2 subscript here to emphasize that $\Delta x' \neq \Delta x_2'$; even though both quantities are distances measured in the $S'$ frame, measuring the length of a moving meter stick and the length of a stationary meter stick are different experiments). Given $\Delta x_2'$ and $\Delta t_2'$, we can use the Lorentz transformations to infer what observer $S$ will measure for the length $\Delta x_2$ and time interval $\Delta t_2$ between these two events.

Comment: I see your point. You are using a different notation but its just reaches as my point..

Comment: @Layla So is your confusion resolved or not?

Comment: "Δ is the distance between two events at the same time in frame ." In general, isn't Δ the difference in x-coordinates for two events in the S frame. The events could be at different times in S. Same for Δ'.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps, but one problem that I see with distances in relativity is how to measure it in typical examples:

A trip from earth to Alpha Centauri, that is 4 ly distance, at a speed of 0,5c, will take 8 years in earth time:

$t' = \gamma (t - vx) = 1,1547(8 - 0.5*4) = 6,9282$

It will take 6,9282 years in the ship time.

The time can be measured by a clock in the ship, so there is no problem to verify.

How the ship knows it is at 0,5c with respect to earth? I imagine it can be measured by Doppler effect, comparing stars ahead and behind with their known spectra at earth.

The distance earth - AC is $x = 4$ ly in the earth / AC frame. It is $x'< x$ for the ship, but I can not see how to measure it. The astronomers do it by paralax, what can not be made in a ship, because it is too small.

But it can be done by calculation, from $v$ and $t'$:

$x' = 0,5*6,9282 = 3,4641$ ly.

Answer (score 1):

> In general how can one define what is Δx and Δx′ ? Since it seems they are not just defined under who is moving and who is at rest but who is measuring the quantity...

No, they have the same definition for all observers. An analogy is differing map coordinates. Suppose Alice and Bob disagree what direction is North. They each make a map of a city, they both put City Hall in the center, and they both give the location of everything else in terms of City Hall. Alice claims that the library is 10 km East of City Hall. Bob claims that the library is 8 km East and 6 km North of City Hall.

They disagree as to whose North is the "real" North, but they are in agreement as to where everything is with respect to their directions. Suppose Alice refers to the direction that Bob says is North as "Bob-North". Then she agrees with Bob that the library is 8 km Bob-East and 6 km Bob-North of City hall.

When Alice and Bob talk about "East" and "North", they are talking about *different things*. When S and S' talk about "a meter", they are talking about different things. Alice's East is a mixture of Bob's East and Bob's North. The "meter" of S is a mixture of a "meters" of S' and "seconds" of S'.

We can define four units: a S-light-second (the distance light travels in one second in S's frame of reference), a S-second (a second in S's frame of reference), a S'-light-second (the distance light travels in one second in S''s frame of reference), and a S'-second (a second in S''s frame of reference). So 8 S-light-seconds might correspond to 10 S'-light-seconds and 6 S'-seconds. S and S' disagree which unit measures distance, but they agree as to where everything is in terms of a particular set of units.

> however if we have a stick and if its at rest with respect to S', then we are still using Δx=1.

No, if a stick starts out 1 S-meter, and then accelerates to become at rest respect to S', then it will now be 1 S'-meter.

When we speak of the length of a stick, we mean the distance between its ends. When we talk about relativity, we are dealing with four dimensional space-time, and so to be rigorous, we have to talk about the separation between four dimensional points, or events. This separation has a spatial component and a temporal one. When we say that a stick is 1 m long in the S' frame of reference, what we mean is that if we find a "the front of the stick is here" event, and a "the back of the stick is here" event, and there is no S'-second separation, then the S'-meter separation will be 1 S'-meter. The S-meter separation, on the other hand, will be larger.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very misleading way to write the Lorentz equations.

Their actual form is (going from S' to S)

$$x=\gamma(x'+\beta c t')$$

$$ct=\gamma(ct'+\beta x')$$

here $(x,t)$ or $(x',t')$ refer to an **event**: think of a light flashing or a train departing or a signal arriving or a simple snap of the fingers. Something that  happens at a definite place and a definite time.

From that you can introduce $(x_1,t_1)$ and $(x_2,t_2)$ and form $\Delta x=x_1-x_2$ and write your form - but it's now clear that this $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$ are the space and time differences between two events.

Now - if you want - you can say that these particular events are the measurements of the ends of a rod.  For this to be a meaningful measurement, either they must both be done at the same time, or the rod must be at rest. (If you measure the position of one end of a moving rod and then later measured the position of the other end, that doesn't give you the length, as it moved between measurements). So if $\Delta x'$ is the length of a rod, either $\Delta t'=0$ (which precludes $\Delta t=0$) or the rod is at rest in the S' frame. Likewise $\Delta x$ is the length in the S frame only if $\Delta t=0$ or the rod is stationary.

Events are primary. Lengths and durations are constructed from events.